# How to get centriod coordinates of multiple points in binary image_matlab

Tags: matlab, binary

Hi I need to find the centriod coordinates of each points (multiple points in one binary image). [image: dotfig.png]

When I use the code

```
  A=imread('dotfig.png');
  B=im2bw(A)
  [b,a]=find(B==0);
```

So, I get coordinates in terms of a,b for rows and cols. I got multiple a and multiple b (for 7 points in pic). Actually, I just would like to get seven a and seven b, which represent coordinates for centriods of seven dots in the pic. I know `ginput` might give me similar value. But dont' want to use manual input in my codes. Any suggestion is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use `regionprops`:

```
 stats = regionprops(B,'Centroid')
```

Here's a detailed way in how to use it:

First I'll generate some random points

```
a=zeros(50);
a(ind2sub(size(a),randi(numel(a),7,1)))=1;
a=padarray(a,[10 10]);
a=conv2(a,fspecial('gaussian',7,1),'same');
b=a>0.02; 
imagesc(b);
```

Then use regionprops:

```
stats = regionprops(b,'Centroid');
```

This is just to plot the various centroids:

```
hold on;
for n=1:numel(stats)
plot(stats(n).Centroid(1),stats(n).Centroid(2),'rx'); hold on
text(stats(n).Centroid(1)-4,stats(n).Centroid(2)-4,...
     ['x=' num2str(stats(n).Centroid(1)) ', y=' num2str(stats(n).Centroid(2))],'Color','w' );
end
```

[image]

Comment: hi @bla thanks for your comments. When I use above functions. I got one "a" and one b only. I think they are centriod x and y over 7 dots. But I would like to get seven "a" and seven "b" for seven points in the pic. Do I miss anything? Thanks ahead.

Comment: by doing `stats.Centroid` you get the 7 x,y positions of the centroids of the 7 dots you have...